# Как сделать видимой Panel, когда они находится в фокусе?

Tags: c#, winforms

Прочитал о Свойстве `Control.CanFocus` и Свойстве `Control.IsAccessible`.Значение true, если элемент управления является видимым для приложений со специальными возможностями; в противном случае — значение false. Написал код, но он не работает:

```
if (Form1.panel2 == element && element.CanFocus==true) 
{
    element.Width = 342;
    element.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    element.IsAccessible = true;
} else if (Form1.panel3 == element) 
{
    Form1.panel3.Width = Form1.panel1.Width - Form1.panel2.Width - Form1.panel4.Width;
    Form1.panel3.Location = new Point(Form1.panel4.Width + 10, 0);

} else if (Form1.panel4 == element && element.CanFocus == true) 
{
    element.Width = 54;
    element.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    element.IsAccessible = true;
}
```

У меня большая panel3, которая перекрывает видимость другим панелям, когда я начинаю перетаскивать panel4 и panel2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать видимой панель которая находиться в фокусе?
Опубликую весь класс на всякий случай :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace ПАК_ИП_ОЭБ
{
    class InterfaceLibClass1
    {
        static public bool isDragging;
        static public int oldX, oldY;
        static private int WidthScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        static private int HeightScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        static public void Dragging(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, string occasion, Form1 form) {
            if (occasion == "MouseDown")
            {
                oldX = e.X;
                oldY = e.Y;
                isDragging = true;
            }
            else if (occasion == "MouseMove")
            {
                if (sender is Control element && isDragging)
                {
                    element.Top = element.Top + (e.Y - oldY);
                    element.Left = element.Left + (e.X - oldX);

                    if (element.Bounds.X <= 0)
                    {

                        if (form.panel2 == element) {
                            element.Width = 342;
                            element.Location = new Point(0, 0);
                            form.panel2.BringToFront();
                        } else if (form.panel3 == element) {
                            form.panel3.Width = form.panel1.Width - form.panel2.Width - form.panel4.Width;
                            form.panel3.Location = new Point(form.panel4.Width + 10, 0);

                        } else if (form.panel4 == element) {
                            element.Width = 54;
                            element.Location = new Point(0, 0);
                            form.panel2.BringToFront();
                        }
                        element.Height = form.panel1.Height;
                        InterfaceLibClass1.isDragging = false;

                    }
                    else if (element.Bounds.X >= WidthScreen - element.Width) {

                        if (form.panel2 == element) {
                            element.Width = 342;
                            element.Location = new Point(WidthScreen - element.Width, 0);
                            form.panel2.BringToFront();
                        } else if (form.panel3 == element) {
                            form.panel3.Width = form.panel1.Width - form.panel2.Width - form.panel4.Width;
                            form.panel3.Location = new Point(form.panel4.Width + 10, 0);
                        }
                        else if (form.panel4 == element) {
                            element.Width = 54;
                            element.Location = new Point(WidthScreen - element.Width, 0);
                            form.panel2.BringToFront();
                        }
                        element.Height = form.panel1.Height;
                        InterfaceLibClass1.isDragging = false;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        element.Height = 320;
                    }
                }


            }
            else if (occasion == "MouseUp")
            {
                isDragging = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно соответствующую панель вынести на передний план. Например:

```
panel2.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Спасибо, надо пробовать.  У меня другие ошибки вылезли. Из-за такого обращения к элементу управления-Form1.panel2, из класса. Сделал панель (panel2)  public в Form1.Designer.cs, вываливается ошибка : для не статического поля, метода Form1.panel2, требуется ссылка на объект. Как можно ещё обратиться к элементу управления из класса? Вдруг сталкивались с такой проблемой.

Comment: Можно в метод добавить параметр `Form1 form` и вместо `Form1.panel4` написать `form.panel4`, а при вызове метода передать  `this`.

Comment: koshe - Спасибо, перепробовал массу вариантов и ваш помог)